# Power of product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't seem to be able to find a related question to what I am about to ask, so here goes;

For $M\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$, $N\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is it always true that for $Z(t)=Me^{At}N=0$ we have $Z^k(t)=MA^ke^{At}N=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$?

I assume there's an approach similar to showing that $(T^{-1}AT)^k=T^{-1}A^kT$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ but I don't seem to be able to find it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've seen the answer below, and the question you posed, in generality in the proof of the Kalman matrix theorem for controllability of linear ODE. I did that about four-five years ago, and had this exact same question which I spent like an hour over before seeing the differentiation! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. The key is to note that $\frac d{dt}Z(t) = MAe^{At}N$. With that, conclude that because $\frac{d^k}{dt^k} Z(t) \mid_{t = 0} = 0$ for all $k$, we must have $MA^kN = 0$ for all $k$.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't even thought of differentation!

Comment: Glad to help, smoking_huge_doinks